# Compiling Friggeri Resume Template

Tags: fontspec, compilation-error, friggeri-cv, installing-fonts, helvetica

I am working with the Friggeri Template from here:

https://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv

I am getting many errors when I compile the Friggeri resume.

I am using Texstudio, with the `xelatex` compiler.

Within the folder that houses the components of the template (.cls, .tex, etc) is another folder called "Fonts", which has the following fonts:

```
HelveticaNeue.otf
HelveticaNeueCondensedBold.ttf
HelveticaNeueLight.ttf
HelveticaNeueUltraLight.ttf
```

I have only made changes to the `.cls` file, but I'll provide both the `.tex` and `.cls` code that I have below.  If you want the untouched template, you can find that in the link in the beginning of this post.

`.cls`: https://pastebin.com/02P1eMBr

`.tex`: https://pastebin.com/vuKrYrZT

The errors are as follows:

```
Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'vargreek-shape' for package(keyvalue) unicode-math-xetex. \ProcessKeysOptions {unicode-math}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found.
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found.
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found.
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found.
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found.
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found.
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/n/10="Helvetica Neue Light:color=4D4D4DFF ;" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d. \ifblank{#3
Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d. \ifblank{#3}{}{#3
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/n/14.4="Helvetica Neue Light:color=4D4D4DFF ;" at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. \section{contact}
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/n/17.28="Helvetica Neue Light:color=4D4D4DFF ;" at 17.28pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. \section{education}
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/n/8="Helvetica Neue Light:color=4D4D4DFF ;" at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ...world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. ...world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. ...world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. ...world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(2)/m/n/8="Helvetica Neue Light:color=999999FF ;" at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ...world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. {Specialization in Commerce}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. \end{itemize}}
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/it/10="Helvetica Neue Light:color=4D4D4DFF ;" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. \end{itemize}}
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/it/7="Helvetica Neue Light:color=4D4D4DFF ;" at 7.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. \end{itemize}}
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/sc/10="Helvetica Neue Light:color=4D4D4DFF ;" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. \end{itemize}}
Font TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/n/11.99997="Helvetica Neue Light:color=4D4D4D. \end{itemize}}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. ...ive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. ...o turn their computers off and on again.}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. ... the art of filing accurate TPS reports.}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. ...ucted for my Masters of Commerce degree.}
Package fontspec Error: The font "Helvetica Neue Light" cannot be found. ...sses and presented this at a conference.}
fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
'\DeclareSortingScheme' is deprecated.
No file cv_10.bbl.
Font shape `TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/it' undefined(Font) using `TU/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/n' instead
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
'sorting' option to '\printbibliography' is no longer supported.
Type 'article' not found
Empty bibliography
'sorting' option to '\printbibliography' is no longer supported.
Type 'book' not found
Empty bibliography
'sorting' option to '\printbibliography' is no longer supported.
Type 'inproceedings' not found
Empty bibliography
'sorting' option to '\printbibliography' is no longer supported.
Type 'inproceedings' not found
Keyword 'france' not found
Empty bibliography
'sorting' option to '\printbibliography' is no longer supported.
Type 'misc' not found
Empty bibliography
'sorting' option to '\printbibliography' is no longer supported.
Type 'report' not found
Empty bibliography
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) cv_10(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here are several issues:

1. In your linked https://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv there is no directory `fonts` included. Therefore the fonts `Helvetica...` can not be found, resulting in your error messages ...
2. Friggeri CV is very old and the mentioned https://github.com/afriggeri/CV is already deleted ...
3. As far as I remember there was an issue with that used font Helvetica Neue (copyright or so).
4. The class used option `vargreek-shape=unicode` for package `unicode-math` which causes your first error message. Simply delete this option!
5. On Overleaf you can find an version of friggeri-cv with corrected option for package `unicode-math` and usage of another fonts including an added `fonts` directory ... If you insist in Friggeri CV use that version ...
6. Do not change an original `*.cls` file if possible, add changes into the preamble of your cv tex code!
7. Package `fixltx2e` is no longer needed to be called with an **current** version of TeX distribution ...
8. Depending on your used OS it could be you have an font Helvetica or simular installed on your system. Then find the correct font name and change the used fonts in the class. To do this copy the originial file, rename it for example to `my-friggeri-cv.cls` and search for the part:

   ```
   %%%%%%%%%
   % Fonts %
   %%%%%%%%%

   \RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
   \RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

   \newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
   \newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
   \newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}

   \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
   \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Light}
   ```

   Delete `,vargreek-shape=unicode` as already mentioned and change the fontnames for your needs... Do not forget to use the new personal document class in your cv tex code ...
9. First you need to be able to compile the template example of the friggeri-cv without errors. Then copy this template cv, rename it to `my.cv` and add your changings to it. If you still get errors you can not solve **please ask a new question showing us the tex code** resulting in your errors (delete personal information before showing it to us!).

Personal Remark: Have you considered to use another cv template, one that is not so old? Search on ctan for resume/cv ...

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your feedback. Yes, I have another template I'm using for my resume. Asking this question was to satisfy my curiosity as I am actually trying to learn LaTeX to be used on a regular basis. I want to learn every aspect of LaTeX, not just to create a resume and never use LateX again. I want to use it very often for a variety of things, so my OP was to find out why this problem was occurring, and how to solve it.

Comment: have a great day.